# type strictly dependent from another (nested classes) - syntax

Tags: c++

Suppose, that we have got iterator class inside container class. We can declare this as follows:

```
class Container{
public:
    class iterator{
    public:
    iterator operator++();
    // .. further methods
    }

}
```

But, header file then gets extremally ugly and non-readable. I was thinking, that we could do following:

```
class Container{
public:
    class Iterator;
};

class Container::Iterator{
public:
    //methods
}
```

But I am getting all the time some syntax errors and I am starting to think, that generally this is impossible to declare things in following manner.

My question is how can we do this efficiently in terms of code readability. Is there any reasonable way to do this?

## UPDATE

Syntax errors I am currently facing are:

```
template <typename ValType, size_t size>
    class ReversedVector{
    public:
        class Iterator;
        ReversedVector();
        void pushFront(const ValType&);
        Iterator begin();
        Iterator end();

        friend class Iterator;

    private:
        ValType m_rawContainer[size];
        size_t m_currentPosition;
    };
```

after this declaration I have a complete declaration of Iterator

and when I am trying to implement begin:

```
template <typename ValType, size_t size>
Iterator ReversedVector<ValType, size>::begin(){
    return Iterator(*this, m_currentPosition);
}
```

I get:

> C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before
>   'Containers::ReversedVector::begin'

Comment: It's possible to do it separated as you suggest.  What syntax errors are you running into?

Comment: From the looks of it you are just missing semicolons after the class definitions. It is certainly possible to define a nested type outside the class. Make sure you include the namespace name if you define it outside the namespace, too. If you still have problems post a complete example showing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <typename ValType, size_t size>
Iterator ReversedVector<ValType, size>::begin(){
    return Iterator(*this, m_currentPosition);
}
```

`Iterator` is a nested type, so it can't appear alone outside of a class context where that return type is.  You need either:

```
template <typename ValType, size_t size>
typename ReversedVector<ValType, size>::Iterator ReversedVector<ValType, size>::begin() {
    return Iterator(*this, m_currentPosition);
}
```

or:

```
template <typename ValType, size_t size>
auto ReversedVector<ValType, size>::begin() -> Iterator {
    return Iterator(*this, m_currentPosition);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) seems quite obvious now. + for implementation in new standard :)

Answer (score 1):

This implementation is perfectly ok. [Live example](http://ideone.com/KEkzzE). It is likely that you have forgotten a semicolon after your class deceleration.

```
class Container{
public:
    class Iterator;
}; // <- Semicolon

class Container::Iterator{
public:
    //methods
};  // <- Semicolon
```